# Did Quicksilver eat the rest of the pizza?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse, marvel

Where have the other slices of the pizza (except the one the dog was already eating) gone after the "rescue"?

Comment: Well, it was a big job.  It's not surprising he was a bit peckish.

Comment: Never let it be said that we don’t get into the big questions here.

Comment: @Paul Oh well, better than the "toilet" questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quicksilver appears to have eaten the pizza. Presumably all that running around is quite hard work and therefore requires a lot of energy.

You may wish to note that a few (nano)seconds earlier he'd also helped himself to a caffeinated soft drink.

[image]

Comment: I will accept this as it is the most likely answer to be true, keeping in mind the facts that the man is constantly consuming something, and the amount of "acquired" foodstuff in his basement (ding-dongs, boxes and boxes of pringles, etc.)

Comment: Tab contains 0g of sugar: http://www.myfitnesspal.com/food/calories/30692455

Comment: @brian - Fair enough.

Comment: How much faster would a caffeinated Quicksilver run?

Comment: @AndrewMattson - 7 faster.

Comment: Big question is how did he actually drink the tab? Presumably the gravitational action that usually propels soda into your mouth is too slow, but he doesn't seem to be forming a seal with his mouth and sucking it out. Worst. Movie. Ever.

Comment: If we go into the physics of it, there are also the curtains on the tree, or the fish' glass, or the wooden table getting a kick and not disintegrating with the force of impact... Physics would possibly dictate that the boy combing his hair in the washroom would get scalped. Don't let's go there. Heh.